# What is the timestamp reference after deducting from getTimezoneOffset()?

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

For example I have this:

```
d = new Date(2013,04,20,14,56,10)
Mon May 20 2013 14:56:10 GMT+0800 (SGT)
dt = d.getTime() /1000
1369032970
```

Now, timezoneOffset value is

```
d.getTimezoneOffset()*60
-28800
```

So if I reduce it, I get

```
dt -= d.getTimezoneOffset()*60
1369061770
```

My question is, is `1369032970` my local timestamp, and `1369061770` UTC timestamp?

Can I safely say that any current timestamp reduced by the timezoneOffset is the UTC timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

The result from `getTime` is in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.  The local time zone plays no part in it.  So if your question was how to get the UTC timestamp, simply use the result from `getTime` without any modification.

The idea of a "local timestamp" isn't very useful.  One might apply an offset to the UTC timestamp before rendering it to a human-readable date string - but in Javascript, that's already done for you behind the scenes.  You really don't want to pass a numeric timestamp to anyone else unless it is strictly UTC, because the meaning of what is "local" would be lost.

Also, when you call `getTimezoneOffset`, you are getting back the specific offset at the moment represented by the date - *in minutes*.  Also, the sign is the opposite of what we normally see for time zone offsets.  For example, I live in Arizona where the offset is UTC-07:00 year-round.  But a call to `getTimezoneOffset` returns a positive value of `420`.  If you *were* to apply it a timestamp, you would do the following:

```
dt -= dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
```

You almost had it, but forgot to convert from seconds to milliseconds.  But like I said, this value is meaningless.  If you created a new `Date` object from it, it would display with the offset applied twice - once by your own code, and again by the Javascript internals.